# How to make webkit SessionStore to work with database?

Tags: python, database, webkit, session-cookies, session-state

I would like to create a python class to work with SessionStore class of WebKit server to save session data to database, are there somebody know how to do it? Thanks in advance.

YH

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would involve using **class inheritance** .

```
class SessionStoreDb(Webkit.SessionStore):
    def storeSession_db(self, session):
        #use this method to store session data in your database
```

This will create a new class SessionStoreDb which 'inherits' all the methods of Webkit.SessionStore and adds a new method storeSessoin_db.